# How can I detect when a user is logged in?

Tags: php, authentication, security

I'm currently working on a little instant messaging project. So far everything has been going pretty well.

The only problem is security. When someone logs in, 2 cookies are set.

```
1) Name: loggedin; Value: {username}  
2) Name: mvc; Value: {userSecretKey}  <-- pretty useless
```

These are the cookies that I use so I can setup the next page. However, I believe there is a far better way to do this. And no, I don't want to use sessions because I have a "remember me" feature.

Someone could just set the cookies themselves and "sign in" without actually signing in.

What would be a better way to set this up? Maybe some sort of changing key?

Comment: Have you looked into [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)?

Comment: Yes, but as I said, I would not like to use them because I have a remember me feature and as far as I know sessions are removed as soon as the browser is closed.

Comment: What does `{userSecretKey}` do? How are you using it? Also, "remember me" and sessions are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "remember me?"  I ask because most sites use that to simply remember the username.  They don't auto log anyone in anymore because of the risk.  If you really want them to stay logged in all the time, then encrypt the entire cookie.  Still doesn't prevent hijacking but it would make it more difficult to guess someones password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using PHP Sessions alongside cookies that are purely used for the remember me feature. You could set it up like this:

1. User logs in
2. You store the user IP and Useragent in the session
3. If remember me is enabled, create a new database entry with the user id, an unique random id + IP & useragent of user, then add a cookie that references the unique random ID.
4. Everytime you access the session, check that the request IP and Useragent match with the ones originally set in the session when the person logged in.
5. When the user returns after they close their browser, where only the remember me cookie is left, compare the request IP and Useragent to the one in the Database
6. If they match, log them back in automatically.
7. Users have fun.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can still use PHP Sessions even with a 'Remember Me' function. You just need to set the cookie with the userid or username, and then, if they aren't logged in and the cookie exists, read their info from the cookie and log them in.

Have your logic that checks if the user is logged in check for an active session for logged in user. If it doesn't exist, redirect user to log in. In your login logic, check to see if the 'remember me' cookie is set. If it is, log the user in using the cookie. If the cookie doesn't exist, present a log in form.

for the security bit, you can use the secret key that get's reset when you log the user in. Would it be hijackable, yes, but if you keep changing the secret key/token the window for hijacking should be small.